# How to insert multiple records into postgres database using go-pg

Tags: postgresql, go, go-pg

I went through the documentation to insert multiple records into postgres using the package pg https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/go-pg/pg/v10#example-DB.Model-BulkInsert .

```
db := modelDB()

book1 := &Book{
    Title: "new book 1",
}
book2 := &Book{
    Title: "new book 2",
}
_, err := db.Model(book1, book2).Insert()
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
fmt.Println(book1, book2)
```

Honestly i dont like this solution since it does not allow me to pass an array of books. Cause the use case i have is that i wont know the number of books i need to insert.

Should i be using transactions here cause i might have to insert more than 20 record at once. If yes, please help as am not finding good examples for this one.

PS: Must use pg library.

Comment: the expansion operator is not working?
For example, `_, err := db.Model(books...).Insert()`.

Comment: plus, the very next example is with a slice of models: https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/go-pg/pg/v10#example-DB.Model-BulkInsertSlice

Comment: For your first comment: It doesnt seem to accept the spread
`cannot use books (type []*Book) as type []interface {} in argument to dbClient.baseDB.Model`

Will try the second one

Comment: if it doesn't work with `[]*Book`, does it work with `[]Book`?

Comment: it doesnt seem to, am getting a different error:

`_, err := dbClient.Model(&books).Insert()
 if err != nil {
  return nil, err
  panic(err)
 }`

Error is: `duplicate key value violates unique constraint`

Comment: am using the slice method above. How can i resolve this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226627/discussion-between-kiran-kumar-and-emin-laletovic).

Answer (score 0):

Just put your book, in array of slices, and insert it, go-pg support insert batch

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).